# Implementar chave composta C#

Tags: c#

Estou realizando alguns testes e consegui implementar usando essa forma:

```
    public class Residencia
    {
        public object Id
        {
            get { return String.Concat(Cidade, Estado); }
            set { }
        }

        private string Cidade;
        private string Estado;

        public Residencia(string cidade, string estado)
        {
            Cidade = cidade;
            Estado = estado;
        }
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Residencia> ListaResidencia = new List<Residencia>();
        ListaResidencia.Add(new Residencia("São Paulo", "SP"));
        ListaResidencia.Add(new Residencia("Bauru", "SP"));

        var cidade = new Residencia("Bauru", "SP");

        if (ListaResidencia.Any(x => x.Id.Equals(cidade.Id)))
        {
            Console.Write("Já existe uma Residência com esses dados.");
        }
        else
        {
            ListaResidencia.Add(cidade);
        }

        ListaResidencia.Count();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Minha dúvida é se essa forma que implementei é a correta (segue os padrões de programação) e se existe outra forma de fazer isso (melhorar).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Não considero essa a forma ideal.

O .Net oferece as seguintes formas de comparar a igualdade entre dois objetos:

- o método virtual [`Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bsc2ak47%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) que pode ser implementado de forma a comparar objetos entre si
- a interface [`IEquatable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms131187%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), que permite implementar a forma com que dois objetos se comparam entre si.
- a interface [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms132151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) que permite implementar uma forma de comparação para uma outra classe qualquer

### Exemplo com override de Equals

```
public class Residencia
{
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var other = obj as Residencia;
        if (other == null) return false;
        return this.Cidade == other.Cidade
            && this.Estado == other.Estado;
    }

    public string Cidade { get; private set; }
    public string Estado { get; private set; }

    public Residencia(string cidade, string estado)
    {
        Cidade = cidade;
        Estado = estado;
    }
}

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Residencia> listaResidencia = new List<Residencia>
    {
        new Residencia("São Paulo", "SP"),
        new Residencia("Bauru", "SP"),
    };

    var cidade = new Residencia("Bauru", "SP");

    if (listaResidencia.Contains(cidade))
    {
        Console.Write("Já existe uma Residência com esses dados.");
    }
    else
    {
        listaResidencia.Add(cidade);
    }

    listaResidencia.Count();

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

### Alternativa usando um anonimous-type

O comentário de @MayogaX fornece uma alternativa, que é mais parecida com o que você fez. Ao invés de concatenar strings, você poderia ter usado um tipo anônimo, o que funcionaria como chave composta perfeitamente:

```
public object Id
{
    get { return new { Cidade, Estado }; }
}
```

E ai poderia usar o restante do código da forma que você tinha feito antes.

Mesmo assim, eu implementaria o método `Equals`, que mudaria de implementação para o seguinte:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    var other = obj as Residencia;
    if (other == null) return false;
    return this.Id.Equals(other.Id);
}
```

Comment: Muito bom Miguel! Seu conhecimento em C# é exímio, obrigado.

Comment: Para legitimar a resposta eis a explicação sobre chave composta seguindo a MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb907099.aspx

Comment: @MayogaX: o uso de uma instância de um anonimous-type é também uma ótima opção, pois o `Equals` do anonimous-type é implementado com a comparação de todos os campos. Obrigado pela informação adicional. =D

Answer (score 6):

### Por que não usar dessa maneira?

Usar uma concatenação para simular uma chave única nunca é uma boa ideia, pois pode causar ambiguidade, por exemplo:

- Objeto1 = Id1: "11", Id2: "1" => Id: "111";
- Objeto2 = Id1: "1", Id2: "11" => Id: "111";

Esse foi um exemplo tolo, mas serve para exemplificar, claro que você poderia criar formas de evitar a colidência dos Ids, mas o código ficaria um pouco confuso.

### Por que usar IEquatable

Bom, como o nosso amigo Miguel Angelo já mencionou anteriormente, uma solução que atende ao bom padrão seria usar [IEquatable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms131187%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), além de ser uma classe onde você pode definir um método de comparação eficiente e robusto ela é uma interface conhecida pelo .Net e esse a usa em outros lugares na forma do Padrão de projeto [Template](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_Method), por exemplo, o método [Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> This method determines equality by using the default equality comparer, as defined by the object's implementation of the IEquatable.Equals method for T (the type of values in the list).

### Como ficaria seu código?

```
    public class Residencia : IEquatable<Residencia>
    {
        public object Id
        {
            get { return String.Concat(Cidade, Estado); }
            set { }
        }

        private string Cidade;
        private string Estado;

        public Residencia(string cidade, string estado)
        {
            Cidade = cidade;
            Estado = estado;
        }

        public bool Equals(Residencia other)
        {
            return other != null && Estado.Equals(other.Estado) && Cidade.Equals(other.Cidade);
        }
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Residencia> ListaResidencia = new List<Residencia>();
        ListaResidencia.Add(new Residencia("São Paulo", "SP"));
        ListaResidencia.Add(new Residencia("Bauru", "SP"));

        var cidade = new Residencia("Bauru", "SP");

        if (ListaResidencia.Any(x => x.Equals(cidade)))
        {
            Console.Write("Já existe uma Residência com esses dados.");
        }
        else
        {
            ListaResidencia.Add(cidade);
        }

        ListaResidencia.Count();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: +1 pela explicação do porque concatenar não é uma boa ideia. =)